# Finding Minimum of Long List Python

Tags: python

I am working with numbers in a list separated by commas. I am trying to find the minimum number in this data for multiple ranges.(i.e. Find the minimum number listed in the range 0-100)

My problem is whenever I run the following code, I get a long list of about 4 repeating integers. Any ideas on how to get just one number? 
Thank you!

```
mylist = []
def sort_data(x, y):
    for line in filename:  
        for number in line.split():
            if int(number) > x and int(number) < y:
                mylist.append(int(number)) 
                print(min(mylist))
```

Comment: `print(min(mylist))`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Sorry I forgot to type min() into my function. I have been running it with the code you suggested-I just missed it when typing the question. Thank you!

Comment: @H.Minear Please edit your code with your input and expected output. This is a simple problem which can probably be solved by a combination of filter and min.

Comment: @NabIlovich I know it is not an infinite loop because it runs within about 10 seconds and closes the bracket. Any suggestions as to how to do it without a loop? Thank you for your response!

Comment: You said they were separated by commas. Wouldn't you want line.split(",")?

Comment: Also, you say you used min(), so you should edit your question and add min()

Comment: @Ethan That is the default of the split function

Comment: @H.Minear, a comma is definitely not a default of `str.split`.

Comment: @H.Minear Are you sure, for me it is whitespace and I need to do split(",")

Comment: @Ethan Weird, it defaults to comma for me- I just double checked. Maybe the data was originally comma-separated. Thank you for pointing that out bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can use:

```
from itertools import ifilter # only needed in Python 2

def sort_data(x, y):
    if x > y: x, y = y, x # x should be less than or equal to y
    Min = None
    for line in File:
        _Min = min(ifilter(lambda num: x < num < y, map(int, line.split(","))))
        Min = min(_Min, Min) if Min is not None else _Min
    return Min
```

- `ifilter` is just an iterator version of [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), which constructs a sequence of elements from `iterable` for which `function` returns `True`
- `map(function, iterable)` applies `function` to each element of `iterable`

Please note that if your data is comma-separated, you should use `line.split(",")`.

Also, if you're running Python 3.x, you should use simply `filter` as it already returns an iterator, unlike the Python 2 version. This code is based on iterators, which allow you to work with large streams of data without copying them into memory, which makes this function very memory and speed efficient.

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you for your suggestion! That worked beautifully!

Comment: @taras, well, it holds the minimum value the OP is searching for

Comment: @ForceBru, sorry I missed a for loop there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
x = 3

y = 95

l = [1, 3, 100, 340, 678, 89, 123, 67]

new_l = [i for i in l if i in range(x, y)]
```

Output:

```
[3, 89, 67]
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor edits to your code should work

```
mylist = []
def sort_data(x, y):
    for line in filename:  
        for number in line.split(','):#added comma
            if int(number) > x and int(number) < y:
                mylist.append(int(number)) 
    print(min(mylist)) #changed tab level
```

Comment: One more improvement would be using a set instead of mylist

Comment: That is true, I didn't think of that. This should still work though,